# Remote Desktop Connection Automation using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I wrote a Python script which automates remote desktop connection. Basically what my script does is opening the remote desktop connection, entering the computer name,the password and clicks connect. Everything works fine when no user is logged in the remote PC. But if a user is logged in the remote PC  then I become also this pop up: "Another user is already logged in. If you click "Yes" they will be disconnected" with two buttons "Yes", "No". What my problem is that I try to read the control identifiers for these two buttons but they just don't show up. Im using pywinauto. Is there a way for python to see these two buttons "Yes" and "No"? I want to click everytime "Yes" when this pop up appears!Can I use other libraries like other than pywinauto?How can I solve this?

Comment: you can use `pyautogui` which provides finding a place on the screen using a screenshot, so you can take a screenshot of the yes button, crop it as needed and then use that to find it and if found click in the coordinates (also using `pyautogui` methods)

Comment: I'd recommend reading [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html) first. You will need some recipes from it. But RDP automation from host side doesn't make sense. RDP doesn't provide any GUI text data from remote server anyway. So you have to start pywinauto script on the remote machine. There are psexec and paexec tools for running something remotely. The second one is open-source and doesn't hang under Jenkins.

Comment: Matiss thanks for the answer. You mean to take a screenshot then next time to compare with another photo to see if the "Yes" button is there?

Comment: Vasily Ryabov  thanks for the answer. I am not trying to automate the script from my PC to the remote server. I just need to login because the script already runs on the remote server and pywinauto is installed there. So I just need a way to click the "Yes" button everytime? Unfortunately I should solve this without  psexec or paexec.